# I am installing cx_Oracle using pip install cx_Oracle and getting an error "Could not build wheels"

Tags: python, cx-oracle

Error message - "Could not build wheels for cx_Oracle which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly"

My python version is 3.7

Comment: The message is pretty clear. You can't use `pip` to install it. The module's documentation should tell you what to do instead.

Comment: I build wheels for cx_Oracle regularly. What platform are you using? What command are you executing?

Answer (score 1):

If it's macOS, try installing xcode and followed by cx_Oracle. I had the same issue and worked after xcode install.

```
xcode-select --install
```